# trouble printing indexes in java sorted arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble printing indexes in sorted random numbers, below is the     code fragment for displaying the sorted elements:

```
Arrays.sort(values);        
for (double value : values) {         
    System.out.println(value);   
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "printing indexes"?

Comment: You are printing the values. Not the indexes (or indices).

Comment: You would need to use a standard for loop `for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { ... }` where `i` is the index.

Comment: Do you mean, original indices before sorting?

Answer (score 2):

The enhanced for-loop is a quick way to get the values of an array, but you can't access the indexes of the elements. Use the traditional for-loop instead:

```
for(int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
    System.out.println(index + ": " + values[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial scenario.You just have to use the normal for loop over your sorted array.

```
for (int index=1; index<=values.length;index++) {         
    System.out.println("index : "+index+" value :"+values[index-1]);   
}
```

Comment: Err, Java arrays are 0-based. Use `int index = 0; index < values.length;` etc.

Comment: Oops... just noticed that. Thanks. Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Another way (maybe more flexible in some point of view) is just to add external integer value.

```
int index = 0;
for (double value : values) {         
    System.out.println(++index + ". " + value);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are printing the values in the array, not the indexes. So if you want to print the array indexes with values by using for-each loop here is the code.

```
 Arrays.sort(values);     
 int i=0;
 for (double value : values) {         
     System.out.println("index is "+i+" , value is :"+value);
     i++;   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Arrays.sort(values); 
int i=0;      
for (double value : values) {         
    System.out.println("Index :"+i++ +" Value: "+value);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of the original index of each now-sorted entry in the array then you should gather an array of indexes and sort them on the values at that index.

```
public void test() {
    int[] values = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    // Grab the indexes of each.
    Integer[] indexes = new Integer[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        indexes[i] = i;
    }
    // Sort them through the indexes.
    Arrays.sort(indexes, new Comparator<Integer> () {

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
           return Integer.compare(values[o1], values[o2]);
        }
    });
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indexes));

    // Or in a single expressive Java-8 line:
    System.out.println(
            // Count the elements.
            IntStream.range(0, values.length)
                    // Turn int to Integer
                    .boxed()
                    // Sort it on the values behind the indexes.
                    .sorted((i, j) -> Integer.compare(values[i], values[j]))
                    // Make a list.
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
}
```

prints

> [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

which is exactly as expected.